# vector out of range when converting to short

Tags: c++, vector, reinterpret-cast

I have this code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> cVec{ 'a','r','t','u' };
    std::vector<unsigned short>sVec;

    sVec = { reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(&cVec[0]), reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(&cVec[cVec.size()-1]) };
    for (auto i : sVec)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

but when I run it, I have this error:

```
vector out of range
```

how can I solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: This is one huge Undefined Behaviour. What exactly are you trying to do? `sVec` should have 1, 2 or 4 elements?

Comment: 2 elements. Naturally, it has to take ```a``` and ```r``` and convert them to a short same for the 2 other

Comment: Char is 1 byte, short is 2 bytes. You're taking the address of the first element and reinterpret the pointer to char as pointer to short, and do the same with the last element? So instead of having one element at each new address you expect one at every other memory address, but still expect to find 4 elements? Vectors are not covariant. You cannot transform a vector<char> to a vector<short> that way.

Comment: @Useless ```to see shorts containing two consecutive chars```

Comment: @MariusBancila which way can I use to solve it?

Comment: Undefined behavior because your code will go past the end of cVec.  (Assuming covariance, which may be valid due to using char.)  As if you have `for (int i = 0; i != 3; i += 2) ...` and the loop never ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing pointers to the first and last character to the `std::vector` constructor. The pointers should be to the first and one after the last character. As the distance between the two pointers you pass isn't a whole number of `short`s the code has undefined behaviour. The following code should fix the problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> cVec{ 'a','r','t','u' };
    std::vector<unsigned short>sVec;

    sVec = { reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(cVec.data()), reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(cVec.data() + cVec.size()) };
    for (auto i : sVec)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can't use `&cVec[cVec.size()]` as this too has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for this answer

Comment: if I work with floats it will be the same?
```std::vector<float>sVec;

    sVec = { reinterpret_cast<float*>(cVec.data()), reinterpret_cast<float*>(cVec.data() + cVec.size()) };```

Comment: yes with the usual undefined behaviour caveats from `reinterpret_cast`

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is probably this:

```cpp
int main()
{
   std::vector<unsigned char> cVec{ 'a','r','t','u' };

   unsigned short* ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(&cVec[0]);
   std::vector<unsigned short> sVec{ ptr, ptr + cVec.size() / sizeof(unsigned short) };
   for (auto i : sVec)
      std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: why I cannot do the following:
```unsigned short* ptr1 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(&cVec[cVec.size()]);```
```std::vector<unsigned short> sVec{ ptr, ptr +ptr1 };```

Comment: @Gigo `cVec[cVec.size()]` has undefined behaviour as it is out of bounds of the vector